# How to set label mouse icon dynamically

Tags: vba, ms-word

I create dynamic labels inside a form and want the cursor to change its style from a standard one to a pointer. At this moment code look like this:

```
 Set lbl = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
 With lbl
     .Caption = myArray(i) ' array of label names
     .Top = i * 25
     '.MouseIcon = "C:\hand.cur" <- this does not work
 End With
```

Unfortunatelly, this does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to:

```
    ...
    .MousePointer = fmMousePointerCustom
    .MouseIcon = LoadPicture("C:\hand.cur")
End With
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! It works. But can you give me another advice. What if I want to load icon from url?